# Pushing default value of form through Django to Flask

Tags: python, flask

so I am trying to let the user select a question to answer after iterating through all of the questions in the database. I want the ID of the question they choose to be placed into the `session['select_q']` variable to be used on another page. The current code I have is throwing a `400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.` error and I think I am not passing the value to the session properly. What would be the best way to pass the value of the choice to the session so I can use that value on the separate page `room.html`.  Perhaps there is even a better way to do all this other than sessions, but let me know!

**pending.html code:**

```
{% for r in result %}
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-width-1-2@m">
                <div class="uk-card-header">
                    <div class="uk-grid-small uk-flex-middle" uk-grid>
                        <div class="uk-width-auto">
                            <img class="uk-border-circle" width="40" height="40" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/user_avatar.jpg')}}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="uk-width-expand">
                            <h3 class="uk-card-title uk-margin-remove-bottom">{{ r[9] }}</h3>
                            <p class="uk-text-meta uk-margin-remove-top">{{ r[4] }}</p>
                            <li><u>Time Submitted</u>: {{ r[5] }}</li>
                            <!--<li><u>Question ID</u>: {{ r[0] }}</li>-->
                            <!--GET TECH INFO<li><u>TECH ID</u>: {{ r[0] }}</li>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="uk-card-footer">
                    <form action="/room/" method="post">
                            <!-- POST to session which set they are working with -->
                            <input type="hidden" class="uk-input uk-invisible" name="select_q" value="{{ r[0] }}">
                            <input class="uk-button uk-button-primary" type="submit" value="View">
                    </form>
                </div>

                {% if error %}
                    <span class="uk-label uk-label-danger">{{ error }}</span></p>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

**room.html code:**

```
<h3>{{ result[9] }}</h3>
        <p>{{ result[4] }}</p>
        <li><u>Time Submitted</u>: {{ result[5] }}</li>
        <li><u>Difficulty</u>: {{ result[3] }}</li>
        <li><u>Tags</u>: {{ result[10] }}</li>
        <!-- include tech info -->

        {% for t in thread %}
            <p>Thread Info:</p>
            <li><u>Question ID</u>: {{ t[0] }}</li>
            <li><u>Client ID</u>: {{ t[1] }}</li>
            <li><u>Technician ID</u>: {{ t[2] }}</li>
            <p><u>Body:</u><br> {{ t[4] }}</p>
        {% endfor %}


        <hr>
        <form action="/room/" method="post">
            <textarea class="uk-textarea" rows="10" placeholder="Enter your response here" name="body" value="{{ request.form.body }}"></textarea><br><br>
            <input class="uk-button uk-button-primary" type="submit" value="Comment">
        </form>
```

**Flask code:**

```
@app.route('/room/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def room():
    error = ''
    try:
        c, conn = connection()
        clientcid = session['clientcid']
        qid = session['select_q']
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE qid = (%s)", (qid,))
        result = c.fetchall()
        conn.commit()
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM threads WHERE cid = (%s) AND qid = (%s)", (clientcid, qid))
        thread = c.fetchall()
        conn.commit()
        #What to insert into the conversation
        if request.method == 'POST':
            clientcid = session['clientcid']
            body = request.form['body']
            c.execute("INSERT INTO threads (qid, cid, body) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (qid, clientcid, thwart(body)))
            conn.commit()
            c.close()
            conn.close()

        else:
            error = "Something is aloof."
        return render_template("room.html", thread = thread, result = result)

    except Exception as e:
        return(str(e))

@app.route('/pending/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def pending():
    error = ''
    try:
        result = ''
        c, conn = connection()
        clientcid = session['clientcid']
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE cid = (%s) AND solved = 0", (clientcid,))
        result = c.fetchall()
        conn.commit()
        #what question to view and discuss
        if request.method == 'POST':
            clientcid = session['clientcid']
            ##grab the question the client chose, and use in the room
            session['select_q'] = request.form.get('select_q')
            return render_template("room.html")
        else:
            error = "Something is aloof."
        return render_template("pending.html", result = result)

    except Exception as e:
        return(str(e))
```

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between Django and Flask here.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I think the issue boils down to the <form> on pending.html .. ``<input type="hidden" class="uk-input uk-invisible" name="select_q" value="{{ r[0] }}">``, It's not posting the value to the Python end through Django, my syntax for this is probably off.

Comment: @DanielRoseman You questioning the relationship had me questioning it as well this morning. Maybe this whole time I have been using Flask code in my html not Django. I am reading up on them now!